# Azure LogicApp GetRows action converts the same column headers with only difference in values of square bracket into numbers

Tags: azure, google-sheets, azure-logic-apps

**[UPDATE]** The Azure Product team is working on this bug and based on the product team response a new hot-fix will release in the next few weeks.

I'm using Azure LogicApp Google Sheet connector to collect a spreadsheet's rows. There are some column headers in the target spreadsheet that are exactly the same with only a difference in the text in square brackets.
Column headers such as:

- Which social media you are using the most? [Facebook]
- Which social media you are using the most? [Instagram]

It's all good in the spreadsheet but when I collect the rows by `Get rows` action, in the JSON output, the column headers are converted to:

- Which social media you are using the most?
- Which social media you are using the most? (1)

I replaced the square bracket with a round bracket and it works perfectly, this issue only raise when seeing the square bracket !
Any thought is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, we can't solve this problem directly. If you still want the header as:

```
Which social media you are using the most? [Facebook]
Which social media you are using the most? [Instagram]
```

It will show the result you mentioned. And in my opinion, the problem was caused by confusion of cell expression.

As a workaround, you just need to do not leave `[Facebook]/[Instagram]` at the end. You can put it first: `[Facebook]Which social media you are using the most?` or add anything after it: `Which social media you are using the most? [Facebook]add anything`. In my test, I add a dot at the end of the header:

[image]

Then the result shows in logic app as:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Hury, Thanks for the advice. Yes I tested this solution and agree that it works. The issue is my spreadsheet is a Google Form responses sheet and I could not change the forms options. These values generated automatically based on the Form Grid Options.

Comment: As this is an Azure LogicApp Google Sheet bug I will accept your solution as a possible approach. Thanks @Hury

Comment: @AmirMaleki Thanks. For this problem, I suggest you to [raise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) a support ticket on azure portal to ask azure support team help.

Comment: Thanks @Hury, will do

Comment: @AmirMaleki By the way, it's not free.